# opening database connection custom adapter

Tags: android, database, adapter

I've a question with regard to android adapters.

I have a class, extending BaseAdapter. Which basically is my adapter. I am opening a database connection in this adapter and writing to a database when the user clicks on a button.

Is this a bad practice to open database connection in an adapter class? if so how do I overcome this?

I am not using the database to query, I'm only using it to insert a value when the user clicks on a button.

Here's a code snippet. I've cut out most of the code for brevity

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String genre = "";

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.featured_tab_sublayout, null);
        }


        ImageView imgFavourite = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgFavourite);       

        imgFavourite.setOnClickListener(favPicture);
        imgFavourite.setTag(position);

        return convertView;
    }   

    OnClickListener favPicture = new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i = (Integer) v.getTag();

            Radio rad = radios.get(i);

            if(db.Exists(rad.getmStreamLink())){                    

                showConfirmation(i,rad);

            }else{

                String genre = "";

                if(rad.getGenre().size()>0){                    
                    for(String g: rad.getGenre()) {
                        genre  += g + ",";
                    }               
                }           

                db.insertOrder(rad.getmName(), rad.getmDesc(), rad.getmLogo(),
                        genre, rad.getmCountry(), rad.getmCity(), rad
                                .getmStreamLink(), rad.getmTwitter(), rad
                                .getmFacebook(), rad.getmWebsite(), rad
                                .getmRadionomyID(), rad.getmAudienceRank());
                ErrorDialog.show(context, resource.getString(R.string.alert_dialog_fav_added));
                /*String name, String desc, String logo,
                String genre, String country, String city, String stream_link,
                String twitter, String facebook, String website, String radionomy,
                String audience_rank*/

            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have good reason to use `imgFavourite.setOnClickListener(favPicture);` but this is not the usual way to listen for clicks **in adapter**.

Usual way is in your activity to call `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {...});` where `lv` is your list view. Replace "..." with body of the onItemClick() which will contain essentially the same as your `onClick(View v)`. You will get position as a parameter so you will not need to use `setTag()`/`getTag()`.

That you you move your DB functionality out of the adapter which is the correct way to do it in most cases.

Comment: i know, but my question is it wrong? what problems could i run into by keeping it like the way it is? is it a bad practice?

Comment: Wrong - no, bad practice - probably, especially if someone other than you will have to work with the code because you are "hiding" DB manipulation in the adapter. No one will expect that and this may cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

But isn't the idea of adapters to let them manage the database ?, I mean you extend newVIew and bindView, and in these methods you got cursor pointing to some record in db, and you are just updating the list in some custom way . . .

so my question is isn't managing the databese for insertion (in Adapter) bad practise ?